# How can i use RDLC Report without installing Report viewer.exe on the hosted server

Tags: .net, reportviewer, rdlc

I have created a asp.net Report server web site using .net frame work 3.5 sp1
currently hosting application on Rackspace Cloud where they don't allow reportviewer.exe to be installed on the Server.
                    So is there a solution where i can  used the Rdlc report without installing ReportViewer.exe.
                          Need a solution Urgently..

Comment: Why would anybody ever want to look at the report on the server itself?  Are you using the ReportViewer control?

Comment: yes i am using report viewer in my application and want it to run where i have hosted the application.but when i publish it wants the reference of the report viewer dlls.

Comment: Is there no way out for this Solution?

Comment: Hey user280448, how did you go in the end? Did my answer below end up working for you?

Answer (score 2):

download the report viewer redist applicable to the version of RDLC you are developing against...

8.0 is VS 2005:

google "microsoft report viewer 2005 redistributable sp1"

9.0 is VS 2008:

google "microsoft report viewer 2008 redistributable sp1"

10.0 is VS 2010

google "microsoft report viewer 2010 redistributable"

then either:

1. install (ReportViewer.exe) the appropriate version on you PC and then get the dlls you need out of the GAC using gacutil.exe and once you have the dlls then deploy the dlls along with your applicaiton as you would any other dlls
2. open up ReportViewer.exe with your favourite archive program (i.e. 7Zip) and then extract the cab file, then open the cab with 7zip and get the dlls you need.

done, cut, print...

this is just off the top of my head - let me know if you need more details (but the above should be enough to get you over the line)

Comment: or see here: https://www.orcsweb.com/blog/desiree/access-report-viewer-dll-files-for-your-application/

Comment: Thanks for the reply will try to extract the dlls and try it out

Comment: so, does it have a happy end?

Comment: I've done this many times at work through versions 9 and 10 of RDLC (and SP1 etc, etc...) so this does have a happy end :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method, which I found very useful:

To get to the files in the Global Assembly Cache folder, you can do this:

```
Subst b: %windir%\assembly
```

Found this solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/cdf81c32-ac7c-491f-add7-d1c0c6c746eb/).